# UI-Router don't route with param

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-ui

I use `UI-Router`. I have a first controller

***vehicuels.controller.js:***

```
'use strict';

angular.module('autoPrivilegeApp')
  .controller('VehiculesCtrl', function ($scope,$http, $state) {
    $scope.awesomeThings = [];

    $http.get('/api/cars').success(function (awesomeThings) {
      $scope.message = awesomeThings;
    });

    // Show Car detail
    $scope.showCarDetail = function (_id) {
      $state.go('vehiculeDetail', {id: _id});
    };
  });
```

***vehicules.js:***

```
'use strict';

angular.module('autoPrivilegeApp')
  .config(function ($stateProvider) {
    $stateProvider
      .state('vehicules', {
        url: '/vehicules',
        templateUrl: 'app/vehicules/vehicules.html',
        controller: 'VehiculesCtrl'
      });
  });
```

***vehicules.html:***

```
<div class="col-md-12">
<div ng-repeat="car in message">
  <button class="medium bouton bleu" ng-click="showCarDetail(car._id);">
    {{ car._id }}
</button>
  <br/><br/><br/><br/>
</div>
</div>
```

I want to pass **id** to my second controller

***vehiculeDetail.controller.js:***

```
'use strict';

angular.module('autoPrivilegeApp')
  .controller('VehiculeDetailCtrl', function ($scope,$stateParams ) {
    $scope.message =  $stateParams.instanceID;
  });
```

***vehiculeDetails.js:***

```
'use strict';

angular.module('autoPrivilegeApp')
  .config(function ($stateProvider) {
    $stateProvider
      .state('vehiculeDetail', {
        url: '/vehiculeDetail/{id}',
        templateUrl: 'app/vehiculeDetail/vehiculeDetail.html',
        controller: 'VehiculeDetailCtrl'
      });
  });
```

***vehiculeDetail.html:***

```
<div class="col-md-12">
This is the vehiculeDetail id {{message}}.
</div>
```

I have use the yeoman generator --> `generator-angular-fullstack`

my problem is that I do not get my **id** in my controller `VehiculeDetailCtrl`.
What is wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `$stateParams` uses name as they are defined in *url*:

```
$stateProvider
  .state('vehiculeDetail', {
    url: '/vehiculeDetail/{id}', // here we name our param as 'id'
```

So, we have to use now the name **`id`** instead of the *`instanceID`*

```
.controller('VehiculeDetailCtrl', function ($scope,$stateParams ) {
  //$scope.message =  $stateParams.instanceID;
  $scope.message =  $stateParams.id;
```

Comment: That's great ;) Enjoy amazing `UI-Router`, sir